# Eloquent ORM query -- newbie

Tags: php, database, orm, laravel, eloquent

I am just starting with ORM. I had a question, this is my tabel --

**table a - (aid, aname, atag);**

**table b - (bid, aid, bname, .. );**

It is One to Many relationship - that is One **aid** can belong to many **bid** but one **bid** can belong to only one **aid**.

So I was trying out this code, In the out put I want -- **(bname,aname)** for all the records.

A model --

```
class A extends Eloquent {
   protected $table = 'a';
   protected $primaryKey = 'aid';
   public function brelation() {
       $this->belongsToMany('B','aid');
   }
}
```

B model --

```
class B extends Eloquent {
   protected $table = 'b';
   protected $primaryKey = 'bid';
   public function getANames() {
       $this->hasOne('A','aid');
   }
}
```

In Controller --

```
 foreach(B::with('getANames')->get() as $b_item){
      echo $b_item->bname." , ".$b_item->aname;
 }
```

Couple of points to clarify --

1) I have to specify the foreign key to make sure they map. Because in my actual case they are named differently.

2) I am using Laravel 4.

Can someone show me what I did wrong and how I can get the desired result.

===== Update =====

```
 class A extends Eloquent {
   protected $table = 'a';
   protected $primaryKey = 'aid';
   public function brelation() {
       $this->belongsTo('B','aid');
   }
 }
```

I still cannot access the **aname column i.e ($b_item->aname)** in the controller.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A couple of things you should be aware of:

1. If you have a custom primary key, you need to set the $primaryKey property on your eloquent models to the primary keys you have in the DB.
2. You can't mix and match `belongsToMany` relationships with anything other than `belongsToMany`s. A `belongsToMany` is exclusively for the case where you have two tables that are connected by a pivot table. In your case, B `belongsTo` A, and A `hasMany` B.

Comment: Hi I have edited my post .. I am still not able to access the aname column from the table A .. I have made all the changes you suggested..

Comment: As I mentioned, `A` belongs to `B`, not the other way around as you have it in your edit. brelation() should be `$this->hasMany('B', 'aid')`. arelation() should be `$this->belongsTo('A', 'aid')`.